# django: after upgrade to 1.2 CSRF raises 403 though I don't have CSRF protection enabled

Tags: django, csrf

I have just upgraded to Django 1.2 and I am trying to run my project. After I login I get

```
Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
```

which is strange because I haven't enabled CSRF protection previously. Do I have to configure something else to have my project work?

Comment: Was this ever resolved? I am getting the same error and I am having no luck at troubleshooting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, that's because you use contrib.admin view for login with a custom template. You should add csrf_token to your login template.

Answer (score 1):

It seems, that CSRF protection is on for contrib.admin views, which I use for login. This is why I get 403.